# SourceTree (Git) Relative Date Format?

Tags: git, git-log

`Git log` supports relative dates using

```
git log --date=relative
```

To get output such as `* user Desc (11 minutes ago) 96cb501`

How can SourceTree be made to use this relative date format?

Answer (score 1):

You could check if SourceTree respect the local [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
cd /your/repo
git config log.date relative
```

And see if SourceTree uses the format specified in the repo config.

If not, you need to enter a bug repo in [SourceTree for Mac](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3asummary-panel), or [SourceTree for Windows](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3asummary-panel).

Comment: Great idea. I tried it as you suggested, but no love. Also tried setting the date format globally `git config --global log.date relative`, but SourceTree still displays the actual date.